# whats the difference between し and と?

Tags: grammar

I thought I knew this but it has just been explained to me in Japanese class and now I am totally confused.

I had always  thought と was "and" but apparently it more usually means "or"; when you want to use "and" you should use し at the ends of words? Is this right?

Or is し only for reasons? Surely there are cases where its borderline if you're giving reasons?

Answer (score 3):

と does, in fact, mean "and" in most cases (the only exception I can think of offhand would be when placed after verbs, which is *loosely* similar to 〜ば or 〜たら).  Usually it's used when you're defining a group:

> [俺]{おれ}は*[武]{たけし}と[夏美]{なつみ}と*[東京]{とうきょう}へ[行]{い}った。 "I went to Tokyo *with Takeshi and Natsumi*."

or giving an exhaustive list of something:

> [八百屋]{やおや}で[林檎]{りんご}とニンジンとピーマンと[買]{か}うつもり。 "I'm planning to buy *apples, carrots, and peppers* at the grocery store."

If you're not intending to give an exhaustive list, you can use や instead of と here to imply that there's more you're not including.

し, on the other hand, is for giving reasons.  For example, take the following exchange:

> A: どうして[学校]{がっこう}に[来]{こ}なかったの？ "Why didn't you come to school?"
>
> B: [熱]{ねつ}があったし、[咳]{せき}もあったし、[宿題]{しゅくだい}がまだやってなかったしもうムリだったんだ。 "It wasn't possible, what with having a fever *and* a cough, and not having done my homework yet, either."

As with when you're listing things with と, even the last reason in the list should have し after it before going into the explanation, if presented.  That said, し doesn't have to be for giving a long list of excuses; it's fine to use it to give just a single reason, like in the response below:

> B: [行]{い}きたくなかったし・・・ "Because I didn't want to..."

Comment: It's probably also worth making a note about the register difference.

Comment: so し is only reasons and nothing more and for everything else と/や applies as I had thought before the teacher confused me?

Comment: Indeed, that's the case.

Comment: What about here:  教育委員会によると、この小学校は「日傘の使用については一律に禁止とするのではなく、個別の事情を考慮し使用を認めている」と説明しているということです。How is し working there?

Comment: Hi @davidpolygoth !  In your extended example I'm assuming you're referring to the part at the end (遠慮し使用を認めている), right?  In this case it's the ます-stem for する, which is being used in a conjunctive manner in this case.  It's functionally no different from して in this case.

Comment: Indeed. I meant 考慮し使用を認めている, though I think in your comment it is accidentally misspelled. So, according to what you mentioned, one could say or write also 個別の事情を考慮して使用を認めている, and that the example I have given is sort of an abbreviation?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I mixed up the first kanji there.  But overall yes, you're on the right track.  I don't think it's so much of an abbreviation, however, as a more formal form.  That's a question better directed to one of the native speakers on the site.