# Are "と" and "から" equal when they mean "from"?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, particle-と, particle-から

When "と" and "から" can both be translated as the English preposition "from", do they have the exact same meaning/nuance and are they interchangeable?

For example, in the sentence 「 確【たし】かに中沢{なかざわ}部【ぶ】長【ちょう】**と** 離【はな】れることは残【ざん】念【ねん】だ。」, can the "と" be replaced with "から"?

Likewise, in this sentence 「やめる前【まえ】に直【ちょく】接【せつ】彼女【かのじょ】**から**聞【き】きました。」, is "から" replaceable with "と"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That use of `と` should be conceptualized as “with”<sup>[1]</sup>, and not “from”.

“Xと離れる” is “to separate<sup>[2]</sup> **with** X”. Since you can both separate **with** and separate **from** something, both `と` and `から` work here (albeit with the subtle difference between “separating with” and “separating from” something<sup>[3]</sup>).

“Xから聞く” is “to hear **from** X”. Replacing this with `と` would change the phrase to mean “to hear **with** X”, as in “I heard it with her (彼女と聞いた)”. Alternatively, the `と` can function as a quotative particle, where “Xと聞く” would mean “to hear that X”, as in “I heard that she is a girlfriend (彼女と聞いた)”.

---

Footnotes:

1. In the sense of either “accompanied by” (*I will go **with** you*) or “in some particular relation to” (*She agreed **with** me*), but not “by use of” (*Cut **with** a knife*). See also: [Confusion with Japanese particle と in its multiple uses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15363/confusion-with-japanese-particle-%E3%81%A8-in-its-multiple-uses).
2. Verb as used [without object](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/separate). (When used with object, the verb is 離す)
3. I understand that in English “separate **from**” is the standard preposition choice here. I just wanted to illustrate the から/と difference. “To separate **from** my parents (親から離れる)” connotes a starting point in space/time from which I am the one moving away, while “to separate **with** my parents (親と離れる)” feels more like a mutual split where I am not necessarily the primary mover. (To complicate things a bit, since `と` can also mean *with* as in “accompanied by”, you can say for example グループから親と離れる to mean “to separate from the group with my parents”.)

Comment: Well... in my opinion Xと離れる does not mean either "part from X" nor "part with X", which would indicate some kind of volitional break-up, but rather simple "be/get separated from" regardless of the reason.

Comment: @macraf Good catch, “separate” seems to be a better translation that will cover all uses of 離れる. I was thinking more in the narrower 別れる sense. Fixed.

Comment: By "separate with" I assume you don't mean the usage of it in "I separated from the group with John" or the usage of it in "He separated the cheese block with a knife"? Do you have an example?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I guess my answer was a little too reductive. I added some footnotes, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! In particular the "the primary mover" bit really highlights the different I think.