# Can I use quotation particle 「と」with noun?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

Here is the sentence.

> いいかげんにしやがれっ　おれは一年以上もシャバ**とおわかれ**なんだぞっ。

Since the word 「おわかれ」 is noun, I'm not sure if I can translate it as "Say goodbye for free life because I will be staying in it (prison, in this case) more than a year". Otherwise, would it be translated in other meaning or the 「と」in this case does not function as quotation?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28611/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「いいかげんにしやがれっ　おれは[一年以上]{いちねんいじょう}もシャバ**と**おわかれなんだぞっ。」

(「シャバ」 means the world outside of prison, army, etc. where you have freedom.)

The 「と」 in that context is ***not*** quotative because in the phrase 「シャバ**と**おわかれ」, **no one is saying or calling something 「シャバ」** either silently or out loud.  It just means "a farewel to the real world".

The fact that 「おわかれ」 is a noun has nothing to do with whether or not the preceding 「と」 is quotative.

The 「と」 in 「と + Noun」 can be quotative in the following sentences.

「マリアに、さよなら**と**おわかれのキスをした。」 ← The speaker said 「さよなら」 either silently or out loud as he kissed Maria good-bye.

When the quotative 「と」 is used correctly, the preceding phrase can always be placed in imaginary (or real) quotation marks.

「マリアに、『さよなら』**と**お[別]{わか}れのキスをした。」

One more example:

「スカイツリーを見て、すごい**と**[感動]{かんどう}！」

「感動」 is a noun, but this 「と」 is quotative.  Here, one can say that the verb 「する/した」 was left unsaid after 「感動」.

Again, you can place 「すごい」 in either real or imaginary quotation marks because that is what you said or thought upon seeing the Skytree.