# Should I use "Te-" form or "Koto mo" for this?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

If I wanted to list my hobbies, I'm not sure if it'd be better to use...

> 趣味は書くことも、素敵なノートと文房具を集めることも、テレビゲームをすることもです。
>   My hobby is writing, collecting lovely notebooks and stationery, and playing (doing) video games.
>
> 趣味は書いて、素敵なノートと文房具を集めて、テレビゲームをすることもです。
>   My hobby is writing, collecting lovely notebooks and stationery, and playing (doing) video games.

I feel like it's the first one but I'm not sure because you can use "て" form to list things and "こと" to make things nouns so I need help.

Comment: Since youre interested in listing hobbies, why not read up about たり? This is a classic case for using it.

Answer (score 2):

To me, both sound a bit clumsy. I would say this like this:

- 趣味は書くこと**と**、素敵なノート**や**文房具を集めること**と**、テレビゲームをすることです。
- 趣味は書くこと**や**、素敵なノート**と**文房具を集めること**や**、テレビゲームをすることです。

You can simply list two or more things ("A, B and C") using や or と. See other questions for the difference between the two, although the nuance would be small in this case:

- [Difference between と and や～など](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17376/5010)
- [Difference between と・や and も for lists？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14979/5010)

If you used も here, the feeling of "also" would be emphasized ("not only A, but also B, and also C"), which I think is unnecessary.

If you used て here, the feeling of "and then" would be emphasized ("A, and then B, and then C"), which is not unnecessary, because these things are not relevant with one another. And "～て、～て、～も" is not grammatical. You have to drop the last も.

You can say, for example 「趣味は食べて寝ることです」「趣味は毎朝早く起きてランニングをすることです」, because the two actions are temporally connected.