# When do you use と、も、や、へ、or か for adding nouns/verbs/etc? What are the specific rules for each of these particles?

Tags: particles, particle-と

I am currently learning Japanese grammar and have learned that へ and も can be used interchangeably but typically も is used and へ is I guess something usually used by older people or when certain words sound weird with も or to break a sentence up in an easier way to read. However, I am not 100% sure when to use the others. I have never seen や used yet (at least not in anything I've learned since I'm still very much a beginner) and I have only noticed か in Japanese shows I watch once or twice. I think と is just for nouns correct? I am sure there is another question like this but I haven't been able to locate it.

Comment: Can you give an example of へ being used for "and"?  I have never heard of this,

Comment: Related [Difference between と・や and も for lists？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14979/45489)

Comment: How are you learning Japanese grammar? Method 1: reading a book on Japanese grammar, or Method 2: Looking at google translate versions of Japanese sentences and trying to match up the E and J words? Method 1 works. Method 2 does not, because language does not work like that.

Comment: Currently I am doing a mix of learning grammar and words from free sources like YouTube and Learn Kanji and Duolingo. I am currently learning the Genki book from a youtube resource, a guy who lives in Japan but natively speaks English. I only started learning about a month ago and honestly i feel grammar is the most imporant thing because its really the only thing i dont understand about Japanese. Also it might be that へ is used in place of に instead of も? I maybe misunderstood? I only get a few hours in a few days of a week to learn while I have internet so I try my best to get what I can in.

Comment: へ may be used interchangeably with に with verbs that indicate movement from one place to another such as 行く. It has nothing to do with も or "and". I would suggest you remove that part from your question and request to be reopened.